# WMI and windows install date, what date is returned?

Tags: .net, window, wmi

I am using WMI to ask Windows about its install date.
Now my software react strange on it and i wonder how installdate is defined
Using the code below

```
searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem");
            foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
            {
                WindowsInstallDate = queryObj["InstallDate"];
            }
```

Will this give me the date that windows was installed using a DVD.
Or will this be the date that Windows was activated ?

I dont have licenses to test it out myself with a real user license.
But maybe someone knows here.

Answer (score 0):

you can get in `DateTime` format as:

```
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2",
                                      "SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem");

foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
{                   
    DateTime dt = ManagementDateTimeConverter.ToDateTime(queryObj["InstallDate"].ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(dt);
}
```

Comment: thats not the point of my question, my code allready worked the question is what this date means, is it install date or is it the date it was licensed ?. (person typing a key)

Comment: its windows install date, because you can also find these value which has trial version windows operating system

Comment: I will buy a windows license to test it, i think this date changes after licensekey is entered. its the only way i can rule this out